# Vertical align: middle for text node

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I'm trying to align vertically a text block. I have a `:before` pseudo-element and what I'd like to achieve is having both aligned to the middle.

Is it possible to achieve it without extra wrapper? Here's what my problem looks like:

[image: Vertical align]

HTML:

```
<div class="fail">Something's wrong</div>
<div class="success">
    <span>Perfect middle</span>
</div>
```

CSS fail:

```
.fail
{
    background: orange;
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fail:before
{
    background: red;
    content: '✗';
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60px;
}
```

CSS success:

```
.success
{
    font-size: 30px;
    background: lime;
    display: inline-block;
}

.success:before
{
    background: green;
    content: '✓';
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60px;
}

.success span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It might be not so obvious from this picture, but the left one is too high, about 2-3 pixels of difference. It matters especially for smaller elements.

So my question is: can I achieve perfect middle with just one HTML tag + `:before`?

Comment: do what you have done in second div

Comment: But it adds meaningless garbage tag :(

Comment: @RoboRobok, I don't see a reason why it's called garbage tag in your situation. Without understanding your code, it is also important for the elements to have a holder / container / wrapper tag to get our needs done.

Comment: Try removing `vertical-align:middle;` from `.fail:before`.

Comment: ... and from `success:before`, too. And remove `span`. I think that's working.

Comment: Is [this example better?](https://jsbin.com/puzebo/edit?html,css,output) applying line height to the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because I dont like inline elements that much, I would do it like this:

```
.fail {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: orange;

}

.fail:before {
    content: '✗';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: This way you will need wrapper for floating elements or clear it. Float property is overused and used in wrong way mostly. Button is inline, there's nothing to like.

Comment: @RoboRobok - There are already lots of questions that cover solutions that will work for you. [This example here](https://jsbin.com/puzebo/edit?html,css,output) seems to work nicely (as long as you only need one line vertically centered) and there is **no reason** to bring floats into this :) Simply apply the line-height to the parent div.